# How to set default values for $_POST variables to avoid the Notice: Undefined index?

Tags: php

### FINAL EDIT (RESOLVED)

I just replaced `if(empty($num1))` with `if(!isset($num1))` and now the conditional **Required!** notice works flawlessly. Big thanks to everyone involved, I regained some already lost powers and I'm starting to finally make it into a fully functional, styled widget :D have a good day/night!

### EDIT:

I have foolishly assumed that isset() is only for checkboxes...
I got rid of the Notice: Undefined index, yet the problem with **Required!** persists...

---

I have the following problem, I've made a calculator for product pricing, but if I load it for the first time it doesn't "recognize" the null value in not-yet-filled-in text inputs... I'm not sure if I'm naming it right, I'm such a greenhorn when it comes to PHP, just started learning...

The form works flawlessly in general, I just want to get rid of this small problem.

Basically, I have following code:

```
$num1 = (int)$_POST['number1'];
$num2 = (int)$_POST['number2'];
$ratio = 0.2;
$utw = 1;

if (! empty($num1) && ! empty($num2)) {

    if ($num1 * $num2 <= 200) {
        $ratio = 0.2;
    }
    elseif ($num1 * $num2 > 200 && $num1 * $num2 < 400) {
        $ratio = 0.15;
    }
    elseif ($num1 * $num2 >= 400) {
        $ratio = 0.1;
    }

    if (isset($_POST['condition'])) {
        $utw = 1.8;
    }

    $price = $num1 * $num2 * $ratio * $utw;

}
else {
    $price = 0;
}
```

and

```
<form method="post" action="">

        <label for="number1">
            <input type="text" name="number1" id="number1">
            <?php if(empty($num1)) : ?><span style="color: red;">Required!</span><?php endif; ?>
            <br />Label1
        </label>

        <label for="number2">
            <br /><input type="text" name="number2" id="number2">
            <?php if(empty($num2)) : ?><span style="color: red;">Required!</span><?php endif; ?>
            <br />Label2
        </label>

        <label for="condition">
            <br /><input type="checkbox" name="condition" name="condition">
            Label3<br />
        </label>

        <input type="submit" value="Run">   

        <?php if($price > 0) : ?>
        <p><?php echo "Price equals: $price"; ?></p>
        <?php endif; ?>
</form>
```

When I display it for the first time I get the

```
Notice: Undefined index: number1 in C:\wamp\www\calc\index.php on line 3
```

(line 3 because of the fact that I stripped `<!doctype html>` and `<?php` obviously)

How to avoid it? Additionally, how to ensure that the **Required!** notice appears only if the user clicks the submit button? Currently it is displayed since the beginning because of the fact that input fields are empty... I don't want them "empty" I just want them, you know... *visually* empty or equal to 0...

I've worked on all of this for several hours now, have found some solutions for that PHP debug notice, but it mainly involves `if (isset($var))` method, assuming I have a checkbox... Well, I don't... The other method with default `$_POST` values was to actually replace

`$num1 = (int)$_POST['number1'];`

with:

```
if ($_POST['number1'] == '') { 
$num1 = '0'; 
else { 
$num1 = $_POST['number1'] ; 
}
```

well, the notice still appears :(

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: `isset` (or `array_key_exists()`) is the most correct way of doing that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe isset is actually what you want; it's irrelevant what kind of input you are using.  You could write a helper function like:

```
function getPost($key, $default) {
    if (isset($_POST[$key]))
        return $_POST[$key];
    return $default;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I don't know really why did I assume that isset() works only for checkboxes...

Answer (score 1):

Use isset() or array_key_exists() to check if the variable is there before trying to process it.

Comment: Thanks! It was still a bit confusing, since I didn't know that isset() applies to every variable...

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use `filter_input()` instead of directly accessing the superglobals.

```
$num1 = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'number1', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
$num2 = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'number2', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'){
    if ($_POST['number1'] == '') { 
        $num1 = '0'; 
    else { 
        $num1 = $_POST['number1'] ; 
    }
}
```

however, maybe look at your code in a different light. What is written is "if I have nothing, I get 0. If I have something I get that.

So set your variable to be 0 by default, and then if the value is available in the $_POST assign it

```
$num1 = 0;
if(isset($_POST['number1'])){
    $num1 = $_POST['number1'];
}
```

Comment: Good point! Big thanks, it's much better from logical point of view! But isn't it better if I write it down with short form like `$num1 = (!isset($_POST['number1']) ? '0' : $_POST['number1']) ; `? I mean, the less code the better, right? Or not necessarily?

Comment: as long as the code is readable and able to be understood in 6 months when someone else picks it up, it's fine. Personally, I'd swap the check to be
    $num1 = (isset($_POST['number1'])? $_POST['number1'] : 0);
So it reads "If you have something, then num1 is that, if not, then it's 0